# Why am I always getting 'network request failed' error in react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, networking, fetch

Currently im working on a personal project. I created a express js api and simple react native app. When try to fetch a simple json form my api app fails. I don't know what is problem?

App.js (REACT NATIVE APP)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import globalStyles from "./styles/globalStyles";

export default function App() {

  const [na, setNa] = useState("Başlık");

  const getTestAPI = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
        '192.168.1.23:3000/api/getTest', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        }
      );
      let json = await response.json();
      return json;
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const get = () => {
    console.log(getTestAPI.title);
    console.log(getTestAPI());
    setNa(getTestAPI.title);
  };

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <Text onPress={get} >Değerler : {na}</Text>
      <Text>cREATED BY FANTA</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

server.js (EXPRESS JS API)

```
    // localhost:3000/api/get   
router.get("/getTest", (req, res) => {
    res.json({"title":"Welcome to the test api get route"});
});
```

ERROR

[ERROR IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yom4.png)

Comment: Obviously it's a truncated version of your code but just make sure your route is for `/api/getTest` and not just `/getTest`. I'm not sure how you have your routes setup but your current route displayed is just for the latter. Double check that and let me know if thats the issue.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ug0anRd

Comment: OK so clearly your routes are good. Next thing I can recommend is try running your fetch command from the chrome console to see if you're getting an error message there. Sometimes with issues like this brute force is the easiest way to find the actual issue.

Comment: when i use 'fetch('http://192.168.1.23:3000/api/getTest')' i get an promise

Comment: Make sure you use await fetch in the console too

Comment: first of all i'm still learning javascript. i copied my code above and i pasted into console. and it just returned undefined

Comment: i tried again and it returned the same promise as before. i copied my const getTestAPI and pasted. after i did this i called the getTestAPI as function and it returned promise

Comment: try with http:// 192.168 ....

Comment: @Nikhilbhatia ok now it stopped saying network request fail but it gives this output https://imgur.com/a/lNOsWSv

Comment: setNa(json.title) before return json, also console log json before return json and share me screenshot

Comment: i have to turn code into this https://imgur.com/a/d318zqf because otherwise it doesn't give me any output. btw still it doesn't give me output from here https://imgur.com/a/aQeLQ7f